# How to set EditText input type like "X123"?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to enter the text in the format of **"X123"**. i.e **first letter is alphatbetical and remaining should be numericals**. So is there any input type which fullfill this requirement or I have to use **textwatcher** for edit text and then change input type of edit text at run time.Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to this Link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard input type like this.

You can use TextWatcher if you want to force it upon your users while typing, but that might not really be nice neither. You'll only get the effect that they press 'wrong' input and nothing happens.

Perhaps its a much easier, and still nicer way to simply put in a hint which shows the expected input, and once they 'submit' the input you check it against a regex. 
If it doesn't match the regex, you can show a Toast, shake the input field, surround the edittext with red lines or whatever you want to show what field has wrong input.

Comment: Actually user want to input this type of string so he doesnt want to change keyboard from alphabets to numeric and vice-versa.

Comment: So your question would actually be more like 'can I change the keyboard type while typing'. I'm not sure, it sounds like something much more surprising and unfriendly to the user than having them switch the keyboard themselves. Anyway, you can easily just try it out  with a TextWatcher and setting the inputtype programmatically

Comment: There even *can't* be any good way of going about this as not all users are using the input method you are assuming here. There are keyboards which have no "numeric" variant whatsoever, the user may also be using hardware or other immutable keyboard, let alone voice input. If this is vital to you, make two text fields with different input types and make the focus switch from one to the other as soon as the user inputs one letter, this is about as close to portable as you could get here.

Answer (score 0):

use this RegExp to match the string

```
string.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\d{3,}") // for compulasory one char and min three digit
string.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\d{2,}") // for compulasory one char and min two digit
string.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\d{1,}") // for compulasory one char and min one digit
string.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\d*") // for compulasory one char and zero or more digit
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Actually I don't want to compare string. I just want this type of keyboard to enter first capital alphabet letter and remaining numeric without changing keyboard from alphabets to numeric and vice-verse.Is  it possible?